# How to place foreach loop inside a <td> tag

Tags: php, html

How do you place a foreach loop inside a  tag?

here's the code:

```
    foreach( $designer_posts as $designer_post ) {
        $tags = get_the_tags($designer_post->ID);
        $imageThumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $designer_post->ID, "thumbnail" );

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th scope="row">View</th>';
        $html .= '<td><p>'.$designer_post->post_title.'</p></td>';   
        $html .= '<td>'FOREACH LOOP HERE!!!'</td>';                     
        $html .= '<td>'.$imageThumb.'</td>';                  
        $html .= '</tr>';                    
}
```

I keep getting an error. Could you help me with the PROPER syntax?

Comment: php couldn't care less about the html you're generating. html is text, like any other text. if you want a foreach "inside" some text, then you just put it there. Just as long as it's VALID php code.  you're doing a string concatenation, so you CAN't have a foreach at that particular spot, because `$foo = foreach(...)` isn't valid php. foreach isn't a function, and has no return value.

Comment: @marc B So how do i get the result i wanted? is there any way?

Comment: What is your expected code or output?

Comment: *"I keep getting an error."* - Being?

Comment: *`'<td>'FOREACH LOOP HERE!!!'</td>';`* oh, that could be interesting as to what that holds.

Comment: Ok, well you have answers below. None "explained" but answers nonetheless. Answers given however, doesn't always constitute as solutions, so you'll need to take it with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach( $designer_posts as $designer_post ) {
        $tags = get_the_tags($designer_post->ID);
        $imageThumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $designer_post->ID, "thumbnail" );

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th scope="row">View</th>';
        $html .= '<td><p>'.$designer_post->post_title.'</p></td>';   
        $html .= '<td>';
            foreach() {
                $html .= 'The rest of the HTML code';
            }
        $html .= '</td>';                     
        $html .= '<td>'.$imageThumb.'</td>';                  
        $html .= '</tr>';                    
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank for this! Noob here!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this :

```
foreach( $designer_posts as $designer_post ) {
        $tags = get_the_tags($designer_post->ID);
        $imageThumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $designer_post->ID, "thumbnail" );

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th scope="row">View</th>';
        $html .= '<td><p>'.$designer_post->post_title.'</p></td>';   
        $html .= '<td>';
        foreach($designer_post as $test) {
           $html .= 'what you want fraté';
        }
        $html .= '</td>';                        
        $html .= '<td>'.$imageThumb.'</td>';                  
        $html .= '</tr>';                    
}
```

Comment: This also works. Thanks for helping out a noob! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php     
foreach( $designer_posts as $designer_post ) {
        $tags = get_the_tags($designer_post->ID);
        $imageThumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($designer_post->ID,"thumbnail");
?>

        <tr>
         <th scope="row">View</th>
         <td><p> <?php print $designer_post->post_title; ?></p></td>   
         <td>
             <?php foreach($array_data as $data) {
                print $data;
             } ?>
         </td>                     
         <td> <?php print $imageThumb; ?></td>                  
        </tr>                    
<?php } ?>
```